# Django rest framework serialize queryset of many models

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I would like to combine 2 querysets from 2 differents models, then I need to order them by date and finally my goal is to serialize it.

So far I did that :

```
last_actions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_last_actions(self, obj):

    prc = obj.product_request_configs.all().order_by('modified_date')[:5]
    psc = obj.product_send_configs.all().order_by('modified_date')[:5]

    result_list = sorted(
        chain(prc, psc),
           key=attrgetter('modified_date'),
           reverse=True)
```

But I don't know how to call my two django rest serializers so that I can return the right data.

If I could make a database view it coult be simpler I think.

Answer (score 0):

Serializers are designed for match one model relationship, so we need to create a custom `Model` for the logic you are trying to achieve:

```
class CustomModel(models.Model):

    def dictfetchall(self, cursor):
        """Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"""
        desc = cursor.description
        return [dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
                for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    def yourMethod(self):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
                        select field1, field2 from app_table
                        where field1=%s and field2=%s group by field1
                        """,
                        [value1, value2,]
                      )
        return self.dictfetchall(cursor)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This will return a dictionary and then you can serialize that response with a seializer like:

```
class CustomModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    field2 = serializers.CharField()
```

Please note that on SQL you can use `as` keyword to rename some fields, the current name of fields must match var names in your serializer.